# .icon .pull-left expressing strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an application with Bootstrap (using the [Dark Admin theme](http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/dark-admin/)) and I included a small user feed for the admin, similar to the Feed panel on [this demo](http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/dark-admin/preview/index.html). My HTML is like this, and I compared the CSS with the one in the demo (so you can assume that the style is literally the same):

```
<div id="feed_box">
      <section class="feed-item">
            <div class="icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></div>
            <div class="feed-item-body">
                    <div class="text">Some text goes here</div>
                    <div class="time pull-left">44 minutes ago.</div>
            </div>
      </section>
      <section class="feed-item">
            <div class="icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></div>
            <div class="feed-item-body">
                    <div class="text">Some text goes here</div>
                    <div class="time pull-left">44 minutes ago.</div>
            </div>
      </section>
</div>
```

The HTML is also structured similarly to the example in the demo. However, when I open the page in my own project, the `icon pull-left` items are all over the place:
[image]

I wanted to make a jsFiddle but when I exported the rendered HTML page and viewed that one, it worked fine.

Why is the indentation of these icons so messed up? How do I fix this?

I'm not at all sure what information is important here, so please let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: At a glance it looks like a floating issue (fixed using `clearfix`) but without your CSS and your HTML it's not going to be possible to adequately troubleshoot.  "Assume my CSS is the same" is never a good premise to troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry, I initially did not include the css. I now see that zooming on the page alters this behaviour: 100% shows it correctly, 110% induces the indentation but 125% oddly shows it correctly again. Then it starts being weird again at 175%.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the clearfix class will fix this:

```
<section class="feed-item clearfix">
    <div class="icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></div>
    <div class="feed-item-body">
        <div class="text">Some text goes here</div>
        <div class="time pull-left">44 minutes ago.</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

the `pull-left` is affecting the items below.

If you're interesting in seeing how `pull-left` is changing the flow of the elements, add a `border: 1px solid red;` to the `pull-left` class in your CSS.